# ¿Cómo cambiar estado de ImageButton con BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

Buena tarde!!,  [estoy experimentando con esta API](https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-android)

La cual es propósito es enlazar un botón a una app, este funciona por medio de bluetooth, este es mi MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
 private ImageButton prueba;
private View view;
String status = "play";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     prueba = (ImageButton)  findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    prueba.setImageResource(R.drawable.sirena);
    prueba.setOnClickListener(this);
    initializeFlic();
    getButtons();


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            enviaAlerta();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Presionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

public void enviaAlerta(){
    if (status.toString().equals("play")){
        cambioImagen();

    }else if(status.toString().equals("pause")){
        cambioImagen2();

    }
}

public void cambioImagen(){
    status = "pause";
    Log.d("","pause: " + status);
    prueba.setImageResource(R.drawable.luz);


}

public void cambioImagen2(){

    prueba.setImageResource(R.drawable.sirena);
    status = "play";
    Log.d("","play");


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    FlicManager.getInstance(this, new FlicManagerInitializedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized(FlicManager manager) {
            FlicButton button = manager.completeGrabButton(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (button != null) {
                button.registerListenForBroadcast(FlicBroadcastReceiverFlags.UP_OR_DOWN | FlicBroadcastReceiverFlags.REMOVED);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Grabbed a button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Did not grab any button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });
}


private void initializeFlic(){

    Config.setFlicCredentials();
}

private void getButtons(){
    try {
        FlicManager.getInstance(this, new FlicManagerInitializedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onInitialized(FlicManager manager) {
                manager.initiateGrabButton(MainActivity.this);

            }
        });
    } catch (FlicAppNotInstalledException err) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flic App is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Esta clase entiendo que es un BroadcastReceiver donde al presionar el boton realiza el evento, instancie mi MainActivity ya que alli tengo la clase que quiero que realice, un tipo de play/pause

```
public class BroadCastReceiverFlic extends FlicBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
protected void onRequestAppCredentials(Context context) {
    initializeFlic();
}

@Override
public void onButtonUpOrDown(Context context, FlicButton button, boolean wasQueued, int timeDiff, boolean isUp, boolean isDown) {
    super.onButtonUpOrDown(context, button, wasQueued, timeDiff, isUp, isDown);
    if (isUp) {
        Log.d("IS UP", "True");
        MainActivity n = new MainActivity();
        n.enviaAlerta();

    } else {
        Log.d("IS DOWN", "True");
    }
}

@Override
public void onButtonRemoved(Context context, FlicButton button) {
    // Button was removed
}

private void initializeFlic(){
    Config.setFlicCredentials();
}
```

}

al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error!! ya le movi de todo y no puedo solucionarlo, espero me puedan ayudar!!
Error

```
11-03 20:20:05.231 21628-21628/letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic, PID: 21628
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic.BroadCastReceiverFlic: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2750)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic.MainActivity.cambioImagen(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                                        at letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic.MainActivity.enviaAlerta(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                                        at letsflic.batzeesappstudio.com.letsflic.BroadCastReceiverFlic.onButtonUpOrDown(BroadCastReceiverFlic.java:23)
                                                                                        at io.flic.lib.FlicBroadcastReceiver$1.onInitialized(FlicBroadcastReceiver.java:39)
                                                                                        at io.flic.lib.FlicManager.getInstanceInternal(FlicManager.java:170)
                                                                                        at io.flic.lib.FlicManager.getInstance(FlicManager.java:131)
                                                                                        at io.flic.lib.FlicManager.getInstance(FlicManager.java:110)
                                                                                        at io.flic.lib.FlicBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(FlicBroadcastReceiver.java:21)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2743)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es ejecutar el metodo `enviarAlerta()` desde el `BroadCastReceiverFlic`.

Comment: Así es!! se ejecuta y me manda el error!! apenas estoy entendiendo que son los Broadcast!!

Comment: El `BroadCastReceiver` lo tienes en tu `MainActivity` o en una clase aparte?

Comment: En una clase diferente, llamada BroadCastReceiverFlic que extiende de FlicBroadcastReceiver (Esta es de la libreria Flic), en este entiendo que hace la función o es el que escucha el botón fisico y es donde van los eventos, pero a la hora de instanciar el MainActivity para poder hacer uso del método enviaAlerta es donde no cambia el estado(vista) del ImageButton según entiendo es porque hace referencia a null o este yo instanciando mal

Comment: Porque no colocas el `BroadCastReceiverFlic` dentro de tu actividad. De esa manera solucionar tu problema sera mas fácil.

Comment: Supongo que mi actividad principal tengo que instanciar BroadCastReceiver, soy nuevo en Android, muchas gracias probare lo que me dices.

Comment: El error que mencionas esta ocurriendo porque la instancia de tu ImageButton no se esta creando correctamente, por eso el error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Buen día, podrías decir como crearla correctamente por favor!!